# Can I launch macros and shortcuts from a second keyboard on Linux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, macro

I have a small numpad keyboard which I would like to use for launching macros and shortcuts, along side my regular keyboard. I can attach macros and shortcuts to these keys (*i.e, numpad 1 minimises the active window*), but my primary keyboard numpad also activates the shortcut.

I would like a way to have the secondary keyboard act completely separately and to then attach shortcuts to it.

Here is the output I get from `xinput`.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ LVT Recon gaming mouse                    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ LVT Recon gaming mouse                    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair K30A Gaming Keyboard      id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard                    id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair K30A Gaming Keyboard      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair K30A Gaming Keyboard      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ LVT Recon gaming mouse                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair K30A Gaming Keyboard      id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard                    id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard                    id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Interesting question! I look forward to what others can come up with. Welome to UNIX & Linux Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While [my other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509014/3929) will probably work on most Linuxes, even if they're many years old, SystemD and udev actually makes things easier:

- use `lsusb` to find the vendor and product code of your additional keyboard. (In my case, it's Vendor 145F, Product 0177. Make sure to have the letters in uppercase.)
- create a file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/90-extra-keyboard.hwdb`, with contents similar to this:

```
evdev:input:b0003v145Fp0177*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7005b=stopcd
```

The first line identifies the device: the four letters after the v is the vendor code, after the p, it's the product code, from the previous step. Every further line maps a scancode to a symbolic name. To get the scancode, run `evtest`:

```
Event: time 1553711252.888538, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1553711257.656558, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70059
Event: time 1553711257.656558, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 79 (KEY_KP1), value 1
```

To find out what to use for the symbolic name, look at the list of `#define KEY_…` lines in `/usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h`:

```
#define KEY_PLAYPAUSE           164
#define KEY_PREVIOUSSONG        165
#define KEY_STOPCD              166
#define KEY_RECORD              167
```

- re-build and load internal databases by running `systemd-hwdb update; udevadm trigger`
- verify the new settings work by running `evtest` again, or by assigning shortcuts in your settings.

When trying this out in applications, just remember that if your desktop environment already uses that shortcut, the application won't even see the keypress.

Comment: Hi, I had another go at this method and managed to remap all the keys! They're now all sending extra function keys!

Comment: I am tempted to create multiple fake accounts just to I can upvote this answer more than once!

Answer (score 4):

In principle, yes. When I last [did this in 2012](http://brainspiritus.de/entries/e20120408-2114.html), the way to go was to try and tell Linux that the second keyboard is very weird and really means <kbd>XF86VolumeUp</kbd> when it sends the keypress for <kbd>Num 1</kbd>, or whatever. Fortunately, there's quite a few keycodes that don't exist on standard keyboards that you can use in this way.

Let's run through this for a single key:

- use `xev | grep -i key` to find the keycodes of the keys on your extra keyboard. I'll just do <kbd>keypap 9</kbd>, as an example, with keycode 81. (NB: my extra keypad has a key labeled "00" but that sends "0" twice, I have no idea how to handle that.)

```
      KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
        state 0x10, keycode 81 (keysym 0xffb9, KP_9), same_screen YES,
      KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
        state 0x10, keycode 81 (keysym 0xffb9, KP_9), same_screen YES,
        request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248
```

- check `setxkbmap -query` for the rules of your (main) keyboard. We'll try to turn your extra keyboard into a dozen or so media keys on that layout. For me, it's

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     de
variant:    nodeadkeys
```

- find enough entries in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet`. The right-hand side is what the application will see, possibly with shift key modifiers etc., the left-hand side are scancodes. I'll pick this one, because my keyboard doesn't have a "calculator" key:

```
key <I148>   {      [ XF86Calculator        ]       };
```

- create a file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/` that maps scancodes to keycodes (from the first step). Yes, this seems backwards. My file is named trustkeypad and looks like this:

```
default xkb_keycodes "trustkeypad" {
    minimum= 8;
    maximum= 255;

    // keypad 9
    <I148> = 81;
};
```

- compile this file with `xkbcomp -xkb trustkeypad`
- try it out with `setxkbmap -v -v -device 17 -keycodes (filename)`. (The 17 is the id from your `xinput`.) The result for me looks like this:

```
Warning! Multiple definitions of keycodes
         Using command line, ignoring rules file
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     de
variant:    nodeadkeys
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   trustkeypad
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+de(nodeadkeys)+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
```

and that looks good, in particular, the keycodes line.
 If you run `xev` now, you should see the new symbols being generated. Alas, I get only a half-victory right now:

```
KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x168, subw 0x0, time 24043275, (1666,897), root:(1670,950),
    state 0x10, keycode 81 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x168, subw 0x0, time 24043403, (1666,897), root:(1670,950),
    state 0x10, keycode 81 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x168, subw 0x0, time 24043403, (1666,897), root:(1670,950),
    state 0x10, keycode 77 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x168, subw 0x0, time 24043411, (1666,897), root:(1670,950),
    state 0x10, keycode 77 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

but after I crashed X a couple of times by accident (do not think that setting the minimum value in the keycodes file higher will help), that went away. Maybe a simple reboot can help at this point. After you're successful, you should only get something like

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x168, subw 0x0, time 26443862, (930,972), root:(934,1025),
    state 0x10, keycode 81 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x168, subw 0x0, time 26444022, (930,972), root:(934,1025),
    state 0x10, keycode 81 (keysym 0x1008ff1d, XF86Calculator), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

and you can verify in your user settings that you can now assign a shortcut to this key, and it will say it's assigned to the Calculator key.

Still missing here: figuring out how to make this the standard setting, also across reboots. This will probably involve looking at udev, and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions might be useful, even though it has an "outdated" tag dating from 2014.

Answer (score 4):

I premise that I'm not a Linux expert, just a user. However, I would like to share the way I solved this problem for my needs. It's  not really a solution like the ones proposed by the other users, but more a way to get around the problem.
I found this software called [input remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper) which allowed me to change the mapping of my 2 keyboards **separately**, selecting them in the device menu.

[image: A input remapper GUI screenshot]

The program offers a syntax to trigger [key combinations](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/blob/115fb787c175e9e7c852be63da4fdd749d605981/readme/examples.md) and seems to have an optional custom [macro language](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/blob/HEAD/readme/macros.md).

However, since I'm not able to write a single string of code, what I've done is simply to assign my macros to a *key-combination* of my primary keyboard that is not already used. For example, in Ubuntu 22.10.

[image]

And then assign that *key-combination* to a key of my second keyboard (in the image KP_BEGIN) whit the input remapper software and the key_combination-sintax:

[image]

Surely not an elegant solution, but maybe a bit more easier to implement for who's not familiar whit terminal like me.

Comment: Thank you, this works great for creating a custom stream deck from a USB keypad :D
The latest version looks a bit different, but it is super useful.

Comment: You saved my life and time ! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

The described `hwdb` modification method will not work with multiple USB keyboards attached because the scancode of the same button on different USB keyboards is the same, you will remap the button on all your attached USB keyboards.

The scancode is different only between the built-in laptop's keyboard and the USB keyboard.

I would try this python method instead (found it in a comment on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Arn8ExQ2Gjg)

1. Install Python and it's `evdev` module (you'll need it later)
2. `cd` to /dev/input/by-id/
3. Without the keyboard plugged in, `ls`.
4. Plug the keyboard in, and `ls`.  There'll be two new symlinks.  Take note of it's absolute position in the filesystem (e.g /dev/input/by-id/usb-0c45_USB_WIRED_KEYBOARD_event-kbd )
5. Exit the terminal.  Create a python file and put this in it:

   ```python
   from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes
   dev = InputDevice('/absolute/position/of/device')
   dev.grab()


   for event in dev.read_loop():
        if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
             key = categorize(event)
        if key.keystate == key.key_down:
             if key.keycode == 'KEY_ESC':
                  print("Hello, world!")
   ```
6. Now, if you press the escape key on your second keyboard, it will print "Hello, world!"